# Should I use `useAuthState` from React Firebase Hooks in `useContext` or directly in components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase, web

Should I use `useAuthState` from React Firebase Hooks in `useContext` or directly in components?

I'm developing a React application with Firebase and using React Firebase Hooks for authentication. I understand that the `useAuthState` hook provides the authentication state, but I'm unsure about the best way to use it in terms of performance and efficiency.

Here are the two options I'm considering:

1. Directly using `useAuthState` in individual components: This would mean calling `useAuthState` in every component that needs to know the authentication state. I'm concerned this might cause unnecessary calls if multiple components fetch the auth state independently.
2. Using `useAuthState` inside a Context Provider: This would mean creating an auth context at my application's top level and using `useAuthState` in the context provider. Then, any component that needs the auth state would consume this context. I expect this would ensure the auth state is fetched only once, regardless of the number of components that need it. However, `useContext` may cause re-render issue.

I'm leaning towards the second option because it seems more efficient, especially for larger applications. However, I'm unsure if this is the best practice or if there could be potential issues I'm overlooking.

Can anyone provide insights on which approach is more recommended? Is there a significant difference in terms of performance or other factors I should consider?

Thank you in advance for your responses.

Comment: There are too many variables at play to determine what kind of impact it will have on your project. Regardless of the approach you use, the Firebase SDK has its own authentication state manager so the "might cause unnecessary [API] calls" concern can be disregarded. `useAuthState` and `useContext` would just be different ways to hook into that information. At least `useAuthState` handles the React boilerplate for you. Personally, I'd keep `useAuthState` in a central location (like a context) because use of the `onUserChanged` hook could get messy otherwise.